# stop setinterval in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code that make an li change it class every one sec :

```
function getclient(FromClient) {
    var NewMsgLi = $("#FriendsList").find('li[id$=' + FromClient + ']');
    setInterval(function () {
        NewMsgLi.toggleClass("NewMsgClass");
    }, 1000);
}

function InitiateChat(ToClient) {
    $("#FriendsList").find('li[id$=' + ToClient + ']').removeClass("class");
}
```

InitiateChat fires after i click on a button the FromClient and ToClient are basically the same id but the problem  is that the 'li' do not return to normal any idea what i did wrong

Comment: The code you posted is syntactically invalid, and it's not at all clear what those two functions have to do with each other.

Comment: i edited please check again

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the interval using [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval)

```
var intervalId;
function (FromClient) {
         var NewMsgLi = $("#FriendsList").find('li[id$=' + FromClient + ']');
         intervalId = setInterval(function () {
             NewMsgLi.toggleClass("NewMsgClass");
         }, 1000);

     }

function InitiateChat(ToClient) {
    if(intervalId){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
    intervalId = false;
     $("#FriendsList").find('li[id$=' + ToClient + ']').removeClass("class");
 }
```

Comment: Without a function name, that first function is a syntax error. (I realize it was like that in the OP.)

Comment: I think it is a copy/paste mistake

Answer (score 0):

look at the [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the interval by calling

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
   //
}, 1000);
//
clearInterval(interval);
```